# Correct way to capture screenshot

Tags: android

I came across 2 ways to produce screenshot.

I was wondering,

1. What is the different among the two examples? Which is the correct way to do so?
2. Will **Example 1** possible to have resource/ memory leak problem?

---

**Example 1**

```
View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
if (v != null) {
    v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, dummyMatrix, null);
    // Possible resource/ memory leak?
}
```

---

**Example 2**

```
View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
if (v != null) {
    v.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, dummyMatrix, null);
    v.destroyDrawingCache();   
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally go with example 2.  I like how you are clearing the cache as you go on with the program.

http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/